# Synchronizing issue at receiver for clock recovery?

Tags: clock-recovery

i have a question regarding the working of communication protocol (for example any protocol including UART, Ethernet or anything like RS232). I read that there are some synchronizing sequence (Fixed number of bits) which are sent prior to any data bits for clock recover. For example some transmitters send some initial bits to synchronize the clock on the receiver end. Once that synchronization sequence is sent  then they send the actual data frame to the receiver. Once the first data frame is completed then there are some guard bits to let the receiver know that next frame is coming or first frame is ended.

Now lets suppose a scenario when the transmission wires are connected and transmitter start sending the synchronizing bit sequence (fixed number of bits) to receiver. On receiver end the receiver actually miss the first 2 bits due to some noise on the line or for any reason. Once the receiver has missed the first two bits the next sequence SEEMS to be not aligned at receiver end (that is my perception). For example if the bit aligned sequence comes in like 000000 and then the true frame starts like 00111011011011100. From the synchronizing sequence 0000***00*** the first two bits are corrupted or receiver didn't receive it and from data sequence the first two 0s 001110110110111**00** are considered as the part of the synchronizing sequence. Here according to my perception the actual problem will start and things will go on until the whole receiver is reset and realignment is done provided the fact the synchronizing sequence are properly read.

My question is that, is my perception totally wrong related to above mentioned scenario or is there any strategy which receivers used to mitigate above the scenario ? or above scenario does not exist at all. please consider me newbie in this field thanks

Answer (score 1):

In most protocols with embedded clock like Ethernet and USB, data is not transmitted directly but instead encoded into a format that ensures enough transitions are present for synchronizing the receiver even if a long sequence of identical bits is transmitted. An example of such coding is [8b10b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding). Scrambling can also be used, for example XOR'ing the data with a known random sequence of bits.

Most of these formats encode data bits into more bits (for example 9 data bits into 10 transmitted bits), which provides extra symbols that do not encode valid data. These can be used to represent packet boundaries, which can then be detected.

Ethernet and USB also have error checking. The receiver computes a CRC code on received data, compares with the CRC code embedded in the packet, and decides if there was a bit error. If that is the case, the packet is dropped.

In addition, with your missing bits example, fields like packet length and other protocol flags would be bit-shifted and therefore completely wrong. So the receiver could also detect that, and drop the packet.

Some protocols include ways of acknowledging the packet was received correctly: for USB it is handled by the chips at both ends of the wire via NAK packets. Ethernet does not specify it: it is implemented in a higher layer in the stack, like TCP.

Serial ports (RS232) provide extremely crude error checking via parity bits, which are rarely used due to how little error detection power they provide. If you use serial or any of its derivatives (RS485) in a noisy environment, then you should really implement error checking via CRC at the protocol level, like Modbus does.

Comment: hi thanks for answer "In addition, with your missing bits example, fields like packet length and other protocol flags would be bit-shifted and therefore completely wrong. So the receiver could also detect that, and drop the packet" --- i understand but thats where I am confused that this bit shift will let the frame to be dropped but wont it impact the upcoming frames as well because guard bits and other frames are also bit shifted ?

Comment: Yes, for this reason pretty much every protocol has a way to signal the start of the packet using signals that cannot be encountered within packet data. For example USB uses differential transmission, so normally both wires in the differential pair have opposite voltage swing. But before starting a packet, it brings both wires down, which is never done within a packet, and the receiver understands this as a start of packet condition.

Comment: Can you please share any link where i can find more information related to question

Answer (score 0):

> UART, Ethernet or anything like RS232

UART and RS232 do not migitate noise at all - if the line is noisy enough to send stray bits, it just won't work properly.

Ethernet is a different and much more complex beast. Modern variants may be able to migitate some amount of noise.

USB (<= 1.1) would be one example that can resync receiver clocks on every 0->1 and 1-> level shift.

Answer (score 0):

UART, RS232 and Ethernet are completely different and unrelated concepts.

What you describe mostly relates to Ethernet frame on wire, most easily applied to 10Mbps Ethernet, or maybe to other Manchester encoded packets like how simplest wireless links transmit data over radio waves.

The packet has a preamble to make the reveicer to see and wake up and to adjust AGC or whatever to the incoming packet. The preamble is longer that is needed and just used to make the receiver to lock on to the signal and to the individual bits. The preamble is usually just continuous zeroes maybe, but the last bit of the burst is a different bit and it aligns the symbol transmission so the receiver understands how the bits are aligned to bytes. So think of it as sending idle bits and a sigle start bit and the comes the data bits.

This does not apply to UART frames as such because the line is just idle until a start bit is detected and after each start bit there is data bits for the frame, and stop bit as idle between two frames.

RS232 is just defining electrical and physical levels for an interface, you can send any protocol or framing you want over RS232, such as Morse code or FSK, it does not define any protocol.